# Write to flash in STM32 - Works only one time, second time gives error

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, flash

I have two functions and I begin to call the function `STM32_PLC_Flash_Set_ADC_Gains_For_Configuration_Index_0(uint8_t gain)` first. It gives `status == HAL_OK`.

But after that when I call `STM32_PLC_Flash_Set_ADC_Gains_For_Configuration_Index_1(uint8_t gain)`. It gives `status == HAL_ERROR`.

Why does this happen?

```
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_127   ((uint32_t)0x0803F800) /* Base address of Page 127, 2 Kbytes */

void STM32_PLC_Flash_Set_ADC_Gains_For_Configuration_Index_0(uint8_t gain){
    HAL_FLASH_Unlock();
    HAL_StatusTypeDef status = HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_HALFWORD, ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_127 + 4, gain);
    if(status != HAL_OK)
        Error_Handler();
    HAL_FLASH_Lock();
}

void STM32_PLC_Flash_Set_ADC_Gains_For_Configuration_Index_1(uint8_t gain){
    HAL_FLASH_Unlock();
    HAL_StatusTypeDef status = HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_HALFWORD, ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_127 + 6, gain);
    if(status != HAL_OK)
        Error_Handler();
    HAL_FLASH_Lock();
}
```

I have tried to call `STM32_PLC_Flash_Set_ADC_Gains_For_Configuration_Index_1(uint8_t gain)` first, then I get `status == HAL_OK`. After that I call the same function again (`STM32_PLC_Flash_Set_ADC_Gains_For_Configuration_Index_1(uint8_t gain)`), then I get `status == HAL_ERROR`.

So why can I only call `HAL_FLASH_Program` once?

---

**Update:**

Here I get the `HAL_ERROR` value. See the arrow.

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_FLASH_Program(uint32_t TypeProgram, uint32_t Address, uint64_t Data)
{
  HAL_StatusTypeDef status = HAL_ERROR;
  uint8_t index = 0U;
  uint8_t nbiterations = 0U;
  
  /* Process Locked */
  __HAL_LOCK(&pFlash);

  /* Check the parameters */
  assert_param(IS_FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM(TypeProgram));
  assert_param(IS_FLASH_PROGRAM_ADDRESS(Address));

    /* Wait for last operation to be completed */
    status = FLASH_WaitForLastOperation(FLASH_TIMEOUT_VALUE);
  
  if(status == HAL_OK)
  {
    if(TypeProgram == FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_HALFWORD)
    {
      /* Program halfword (16-bit) at a specified address. */
      nbiterations = 1U;
    }
    else if(TypeProgram == FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_WORD)
    {
      /* Program word (32-bit = 2*16-bit) at a specified address. */
      nbiterations = 2U;
    }
    else
    {
      /* Program double word (64-bit = 4*16-bit) at a specified address. */
      nbiterations = 4U;
    }

    for (index = 0U; index < nbiterations; index++)
    {
      FLASH_Program_HalfWord((Address + (2U*index)), (uint16_t)(Data >> (16U*index)));

        /* Wait for last operation to be completed */
        status = FLASH_WaitForLastOperation(FLASH_TIMEOUT_VALUE); <--- HERE!
    
        /* If the program operation is completed, disable the PG Bit */
        CLEAR_BIT(FLASH->CR, FLASH_CR_PG);
      /* In case of error, stop programming procedure */
      if (status != HAL_OK)
      {
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  /* Process Unlocked */
  __HAL_UNLOCK(&pFlash);

  return status;
}
```

---

**Update 2:**

I get the error here. Error code is: `1`.
See the arrow.

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef FLASH_WaitForLastOperation(uint32_t Timeout)
{
  /* Wait for the FLASH operation to complete by polling on BUSY flag to be reset.
     Even if the FLASH operation fails, the BUSY flag will be reset and an error
     flag will be set */
     
  uint32_t tickstart = HAL_GetTick();
     
  while(__HAL_FLASH_GET_FLAG(FLASH_FLAG_BSY)) 
  { 
    if (Timeout != HAL_MAX_DELAY)
    {
      if((Timeout == 0U) || ((HAL_GetTick()-tickstart) > Timeout))
      {
        return HAL_TIMEOUT;
      }
    }
  }
  
  /* Check FLASH End of Operation flag  */
  if (__HAL_FLASH_GET_FLAG(FLASH_FLAG_EOP))
  {
    /* Clear FLASH End of Operation pending bit */
    __HAL_FLASH_CLEAR_FLAG(FLASH_FLAG_EOP);
  }
  
  if(__HAL_FLASH_GET_FLAG(FLASH_FLAG_WRPERR)  || 
     __HAL_FLASH_GET_FLAG(FLASH_FLAG_PGERR))
  {
    /*Save the error code*/
    FLASH_SetErrorCode();
    return HAL_ERROR; <--- HERE!
  }

  /* There is no error flag set */
  return HAL_OK;
}
```

Error codes:

```
#define HAL_FLASH_ERROR_NONE      0x00U  /*!< No error */
#define HAL_FLASH_ERROR_PROG      0x01U  /*!< Programming error */
#define HAL_FLASH_ERROR_WRP       0x02U  /*!< Write protection error */
```

---

**Minimal working example:**

When I call this, at the startup (before `while(1)` in `main.c`) then I get the error.

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef status = HAL_FLASH_Unlock();
if(status != HAL_OK)
    Error_Handler();
uint16_t prescaler1 = 100;
status = HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_HALFWORD, ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_127, prescaler1);
if(status != HAL_OK)
    Error_Handler(); <--- HERE!
status = HAL_FLASH_Lock();
if(status != HAL_OK)
    Error_Handler();
```

Same error code `1 == HAL_FLASH_ERROR_PROG`

Comment: Well, it's your code so you can debug what it returns when it returns something else than HAL_OK. And then you can debug where and why it returns other than HAL_OK.

Comment: What's your flash timeout value? Have you tried much larger (maximum/unlimited if there is one) values? Where inside that function does it fail?

Comment: @Ilya It has nothing to do with time out. Instead I get an error code. See my updated question. Thanks.

Comment: @NaziBhattacharya now your job is to figure out whether it's FLASH_FLAG_WRPERR or FLASH_FLAG_PGERR, what they mean and where and why they are set.

Comment: @Ilya This `__HAL_FLASH_GET_FLAG(FLASH_FLAG_PGERR) == 1`

Comment: @NaziBhattacharya now you open the defition of that function and flag name, check what register it belongs to, open reference manual, find that register and that flag bit and check what it means. Quick googling says it's "program error flag". The reference manual should have a detailed description about what causes this error

Comment: @Ilya I have found a way to produce a minimal working example. Yes. I will read the reference manual now. See my updated code.

Comment: @NaziBhattacharya try inserting a little delay (a few cycles, like a for loop) between flash unlock and flash program function. In case unlock takes some time and you try to program flash before unlocking is finished.

Comment: @Ilya Do you think I'm using wrong address? If you look at page 63/915 at `PGERR` https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00041563-stm32f37xxx-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf it says `Set by hardware when an address to be programmed contains a value different 
from '0xFFFF' before programming.`

Comment: Because `PGERR == 1` and that cause the error.

Comment: @NaziBhattacharya this is not something one can quickly reply, it's a matter of proper debugging, reading, trial and error. I searched for PGERR in the document, check pages 53 and 56. Keep digging from there. Check that you do everything in the right order, check that all the values you pass as parameters are what you think they are, etc. You need to write in 16-bit aligned addresses, respect address. The error code suggests that you need to erase before you can write again (0xFFFF = empty, non-0xFFFF means something was written in there). Erasing goes by pages. Can't just overwrite.

Comment: check this: https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009Xkb4fSAB/unable-to-write-to-flash-memory "You can only program flash bits from 1 to 0. This is generic to flash memory technology and is not specific to the STM32." You can only program that 16-bit half-word if and only if it's 0xFFFF. If it's not, you must erase it first. And, again, you'll have to erase a whole page, because it's flash.

Comment: @Ilya So I have to erase, before I write? I have an STM32 example for that from my STM32 repository library.

Comment: I never used that thing and I never wrote anything to STM32 flash myself (didn't get my hands on flash yet), but yes. According to my findings, you have to erase before writing (and I'm pretty sure about it). Try erasing a page before writing to it, I see no reasons for it not to work. This is exactly what error flag suggests too. This is also why you could write the first time - it was initially empty. But you couldn't re-write it without erasing.

Comment: @Ilya I understand! I will try that. I till try to erase just one address, instead of a whole page.

Comment: @NaziBhattacharya you can't erase one address. That's not how flash works. You can erase either in pages or entirely (mass erase). No other way.

Comment: @Ilya Ok. I understand. According to page 49. I have an address for Page 127. `0x0803 F800 - 0x0803 FFFF` But that's a range. So what's the real address to Page 127?  The memory page 127.

Comment: @NaziBhattacharya page is a page because it's many addresses. Starting address should be the address of the page, in your case 0x0803F800. If you're using library (and you are), there must be some function and probably an existing parameter for every page.

Comment: @Ilya Well. I have an STM32 example that says `#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_127   ((uint32_t)0x0803F800) /* Base address of Page 127, 2 Kbytes */` So I guess that the address of page 127 is `0x0803F800`.

Comment: Please, stop reporting every tiny revelation. You clearly understand things. Try it, play with it. It's not like you can break anything, there is always ST-Link to recover you even if you botch up something in the wrong place of flash. More confidence, you're doing it right. And yes, as expected and comes logically, the address of the page is the address of the first element of the page.

Comment: @Ilya It's working now for me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Ilya If you want, write an answer. The answer was that I need to erase first, then write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In flash memory, you can only write bit "0" over "1". Therefore, you can only write something to the memory cell if and only it's 0xFFFF (16-bit half-word), otherwise you get an error flag PGERR in the flash status register that's

> Set by hardware when an address to be programmed contains a value
> different  from '0xFFFF' before programming

This explains why you could write it the first time, but not the second time. While memory address was erased - it had 0xFFFF - you could write to it once. But once it's written, you can't simply overwrite it, you need to erase it first.

You can only erase flash in pages or entirely, there is no mechanism to erase a memory under a single address. Therefore, you need to erase the page that contains the memory address that you want to write to. Obviously, everything on the page will be erased, so if you want to change only some data on the page, you'll have to read it out before erasing and write it back there.

As you can see, Flash is not exactly well-suited to hold small changing values, it's much better for more static chunks of data, such as your very program. Make sure you check Flash life expectancy - how many write/erase cycles it can take. No need to worry about it while you're just practicing, but it's not something you can safely forget.